# Converting SQL to LINQ: Rolling Average

Tags: sql, linq

I am trying to write the equivalent LINQ for this rolling average SQL statement but I am struggling with how to use the same table (`BulbSales`) twice aliased as `x` and `y`.

Can you help?

```
SELECT x.Id, AVG(y.Sales) moving_average
FROM BulbSales x, BulbSales y
WHERE x.Id>=6 AND x.Id BETWEEN y.Id AND y.Id+5 
GROUP BY x.Id
ORDER BY x.Id
```

Comment: What LINQ provider? Linq2SQL, NHibernate, Entity Framework, LLBLGen, .. something else??

Comment: you should cehck out LinqPad (for windows), it will let you do linq on the fly, and even connect to a db.  it's neat!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is LINQ to SQL, you can try:

```
var query = from x in context.BulbSales
            from y in context.BulbSales
            where x.Id >= 6 && x.Id >= y.Id && x.Id <= (y.Id + 5)
            group new { x.Id, y.Sales } by x.Id into g
            orderby g.Key
            select new { Id = g.Key, Average = g.Average(tuple => tuple.Sales) };
```

This produces the SQL:

```
SELECT [t2].[Id], [t2].[value] AS [Average]
FROM (
    SELECT AVG([t1].[Sales]) AS [value], [t0].[Id]
    FROM [dbo].[BulbSales] AS [t0], [dbo].[BulbSales] AS [t1]
    WHERE ([t0].[Id] >= @p0) AND ([t0].[Id] >= [t1].[Id]) AND ([t0].[Id] <= ([t1].[Id] + @p1))
    GROUP BY [t0].[Id]
    ) AS [t2]
ORDER BY [t2].[Id]
```

Comment: This looks like a self-join.  Would it be better to express it that way or does it not matter?

Comment: @nycdan: This is not an equi-join, so a `SelectMany` (two `from` clauses) is normally the best option.

Comment: interesting.  I hadn't considered comparing them before but looking now, most seem to feel performance differences are not significant and to go with what feels best.  Either way, it's good to have another option.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks ANI that is great, the subtlety i missed was the way you did the 'Group new' I was using Group By and it gave me a strange error that i could not figure out!